# Can I target a dropped line in a list with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here I have a list within a list. If one of the list items drops a line, I wish to indent it with CSS. I have tried to use this CSS:

```
li:not(::first-line) {
  text-indent: 15px;
}
```

But this isn't working.
Here's the code example for this:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

li:not(::first-line) {
  color: blue;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-indent: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div>
  <ol>
    <li>Un</li>
    <li>Deux</li>
    <li>
      Trois
      <ol>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>
          B
          <br />
          TEXT
        </li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Quatre</li>
    <li>Canq</li>
    <li>
      Six
      <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to target the word "TEXT"

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. Demos are great but only as support for what is actually in the question. Questions should be self contained and we shouldn't have to go off site just to do initial review of your issue

Comment: You can make a running demo (of HTML and CSS) here on Stack Overflow using Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar).

Comment: Might want to take a look at this first https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line#allowable_properties

Answer (score 2):

This may be the effect you are looking for?

```
li {
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for! However I don't understand why this also effects the list items that contain child lists?

Comment: You could change the selector to `li li { ...`  and only target the nested lists. But i would recommend enhancing your HTML, maybe adding something like `.dropped-text { padding-left: 15px }`. The markup as is looks very fragile.